# How to resolve sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Here is the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.posts - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

[image: 1]

Please see the image.

Comment: "I don't know how properly upload problems here." - Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You missed `db` in `class User` in the line

```
posts=relationship("BlogPost", back_populates='auther')
```

correct it to

```
posts=db.relationship("BlogPost", back_populates='auther')
```